# How to get a custom media field and display it as an image caption in Wordpress posts

Tags: php, wordpress, image, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have added a custom media field to my Wordpress theme:

```php
function add_copyright($attachment_id)
{
    if (isset($_REQUEST['attachments'][$attachment_id]['media_copyright'])) {
        $media_copyright = $_REQUEST['attachments'][$attachment_id]['media_copyright'];
        update_post_meta($attachment_id, 'media_copyright', $media_copyright);

    }
}

add_action('edit_attachment', 'add_copyright');
```

I would like to display this field on all images on my site automatically. Is it possible to add a `div` below each image that is inserted into the post to which I can add the copyright information, without the user having to do it themselves when they create a new post or page?

**Edit to include more code**
The content of the post is displayed using the following:

```php
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 blog-main"> 
            <section>
                    <?php
                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                        ?>
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <hr/>
                    <small><?php the_time('jS F Y') ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></small>
                    <hr/>
                    <div class="entry-content-page">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                        $posttags = get_the_tags();
                        if ($posttags) {
                            foreach($posttags as $tag) {
                                $tag_link = get_tag_link($tag);
                                $tag_link = add_query_arg(array('cat' => get_the_category()[0]->cat_ID), $tag_link);
                                echo "<span class='tag'>";
                                echo "<a href='". $tag_link ."'>";
                                echo $tag->name;
                                echo "</a>";
                                echo "</span>";
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                    <hr/>
                    <?php comments_template(); ?>
                    <?php endwhile;
                     ?>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 offset-sm-1">
            <?php get_sidebar('category'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The markup produced around an image looks like this:

```html
<div class="entry-content-page">
    <p>This is the opening text for the blog post</p>
    <figure class="wp-block-image size-large">
        <img loading="lazy" width="768" height="1024" src="http://localhost:8080/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/17-Sample-Image-768x1024.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-5" srcset="http://localhost:8080/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/17-Sample-Image-768x1024.jpg 768w, http://localhost:8080/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/17-Sample-Image-225x300.jpg 225w, http://localhost:8080/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/17-Sample-Image-1152x1536.jpg 1152w, http://localhost:8080/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/17-Sample-Image-1536x2048.jpg 1536w, http://localhost:8080/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/17-Sample-Image-scaled.jpg 1920w" sizes="(max-width: 768px) 100vw, 768px">
    </figure>
</div>
```

I would like to add a `div` after the image which includes the content from the media's custom fields.

Image is inserted into the blog post using the admin console:
[image: The image being added to the post]

It is the displayed like this, and I want to auto caption it:
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Ruvee. I have added more details to the post, and I will make sure I'm sanitising the input